# What is the use of diode D301, D302, D303 and pull up resistors R301,R302, R303 on SPI bus?

Tags: resistors, diodes, spi

I have seen the schematic of SPI with diode and pull-up resistors. I wanted to know the use of the use of this. Can I remove the diode on the PCB and place just the pull-up resistor?

It is connected to an Arduino Nano every which works at 5V.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it's connected to nano every which is working at 5V

Then the pull-ups and diodes form a voltage-translator. The 5V coming from the host (Arduino nano, in your case) may damage the chip as the maximum accepted input is about 3.6V.

When the host (Arduino nano) sends 1 (5V) on any of the lines it'll be blocked by the respective diode so the chip will see 1 (3V3) through the pull up. When the host sends 0 (0V) the diode will be in conduction so the chip will see a diode drop which is expected to be something between 0.2~0.6V, and this translates to 0 on chip-side.

There's one thing I noticed but probably not that important: Assuming the diodes are fast Schottky diodes, *(so the forward drop should be about 0.2V)*, when the nano's output changes from 1 to 0 (5V to 0V), I don't know how long it takes to drop to zero but, the diode will start conducting when the signal at Arduino-side reaches 3.1V:-

[image]

There's a low risk of getting communication problems, especially if the rise & fall times are long enough.

---

SDO and DRDY (Data Ready - probably open drain/collector) don't require these because, probably, Arduino is happy with 3.3V (if SDO goes to Arduino).

> Can I remove the diode on the PCB and place just the pull-up resistor?

No.

Comment: DRDY has a X at the end of wire on the schematic, so possibly DRDY isn't connected to anything.

Comment: @ChesterGillon yes, the screenshot says so but we can't know if it's going to be left floating i.e. the schematic might be incomplete for now.